# Can an answer on a question be merged?

Tags: discussion

So, I lost 30 points on this decent answer to [When did we stop practicing Exodus 35:2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24867/when-did-we-stop-practicing-exodus-352/24873#24873).

The question was deemed a duplicate, although I sort of disagree.  The question is, why didn't the answer move when the question was deleted?

Comment: I think merging answers is a manual thing. The mods have to intentionally do it. Deleting posts is a voting process done by the community.

Comment: @fredsbend: Except it wasn't a community deletion in this case as I hit the button myself on request of the OP. Given that Wax is also uncertain about whether the question was a dupe, I wouldn't be surprised if it got undeleted and even reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've chosen to take a slightly different tack here.

I've undeleted and reopened the question. The deletion was originally performed at the request of the author, I've confirmed with him that it's OK for him to remain attached to the post rather than annonymize it.

I've chosen to overrule a community closure here. Somethign I do not take lightly, it's a rare enough event that we get 5 close votes on a question (though it's more common than in other places), that I'd rather not do it if it can be avoided. However, you gave me a diamond for a reason and occasionally, I'm going to use it.

The main reason that I've chosen to use this authority here is that, while the particular question *does* cover a good bit of the ground that it's proposed duplicate covers, it's focusing on a specific aspect. The *when*, yes, the *when* is to some degree implied in the other questions, but I think there is something to be learned and that's proven by a very good answer.

Obviously, my decision isn't final here. If 5 different members of the community still think it's a dupe, they're welcome to close it.

Comment: Thanks @waxeagle!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it wasn't a dup (I never thought it was) - however since it was flagged as a dup and closed, I asked for it to be deleted.  I have no problem with the question existing and I find AG's answer very good.  However I felt that since it was marked as a dup, there was no reason for it to exist.

I'm glad that it was determined by others to not be a dup and reopened.  I'm sorry for the confusion of the 30 points - however you have 39.7k points... would 30 really kill you? :D

Comment: :)  I lost another 25 today too.  Sadly, I base way too much of my self-worth on that number.  Besides, I'm getting so close to 40!  (Seriously, no, it wouldn't have killed me.  Really, I thought it a decent answer and didn't want to lose it.)

Comment: @AffableGeek You a good guy, I'm glad you're around.

Comment: We eventually delete most closed questions _except duplicates_. All SE sites try try to keep duplicates around as signposts to the open questions on the same topic for people that search using different wording. Closed duplicates serve a valid ongoing purpose (although sometimes we do try to merge answers if there is good stuff in both places).